# How does Amazon Redshift reconstruct a row from columnar storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

[Amazon describes columnar storage like this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_columnar_storage_disk_mem_mgmnt.html):

[image]

So I guess this means in what PostgreSQL would call the "heap", blocks contain all the values for one column, then the next column, and so on.

Say I want to query for all people in their 30's, and I want to know their names. So columnar storage means less IO is required to read just the age of every row and find those that are 30-something, because all the other columns don't need to be read. Also maybe some efficient compression can be applied. That's neat, I guess.

Then what? This data structure alone doesn't explain how anything useful can happen after that. After determining what records are 30-something, how are the associated names found? What data structure is used? What are its performance characteristics?

Answer (score 1):

If the Age column is the **Sort Key**, then the rows in the table will be stored in order of Age. This is great, because each 1MB storage block on disk keeps data for only one column, and it keeps note of the **minimum and maximum values** within the block.

Thus, searching for the rows that contain an Age of 30 means that Redshift can "skip over" blocks that do not contain `Age=30`. Since reading from disk is the slowest part of a database, this means it can operate much faster.

Once it has found the blocks that *potentially* contain `Age=30`, it reads those blocks from disk. Blocks are compressed, so they might contain much more data than the 1MB on disk. This means many rows can be read with fewer disk accesses.

Once those blocks are decompressed into memory, it finds the rows with `Age=30` and then loads the corresponding blocks for the `Name` column. The compression ratio would be different for the Name column since it is text and is not sorted, so this might result in loading more blocks from disk for `Name` than for `Age`.

Redshift then assembles the data from `Name` and `Age` for the desired rows and performs any remaining operations.

These operations are also **parallelized across multiple nodes based on the Distribution Key**, which distributed data based on a given column (or replicates it between nodes for often-used tables). Data is typically distributed based upon a column that is frequently used in `JOIN` statements so that similar data is co-located on the same node. Each node returns its data to the Leader Node, which combines the data and provides the final results.

**Bottom line:** Minimise the amount of data read from disk and parallelize operations on separate nodes.

Comment: I believe key part there is **it finds the rows with Age=30 and then loads the corresponding blocks for the Name column.** 
Follow-up question:
 Finding rows must be getting collection of ctid (or equivalent in redshift). I believe this information must contain block location for each column to get values for **Name** column or other columns if selected in query. Is it so?

Comment: I don't know the details, but I imagine each block contains a "starting row number", so Redshift can identify which block contains which rows. This will vary by column, since some columns contain less information and compress differently. There are some warnings about not compressing the Sort Key columns because it can result in having to retrieve too many corresponding block for other columns. There's various articles about it, such as: [Why You Should Not Compress RedShift Sort Key Column](https://thedataguy.in/redshift-do-not-compress-sort-key-column/)

Comment: "Redshift then assembles the data from Name and Age for the desired rows", yes, but _how_? I appreciate that you took the time to answer but I'm really looking for details on this one part.

Comment: That would be the mysterious stuff that the Leader Node does while combining the responses that come back from each Compute Node. If you're looking for "deeper" information about how Redshift operates, I recommend viewing: [AWS re:Invent 2018: Deep Dive and Best Practices for Amazon Redshift - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJDtQom7SAA)

Comment: No, I don't think it's the leader node. All the data for a row is on some compute node, so except for trivial queries involving just one column the compute node must somehow find the data for the other columns of the relevant rows before anything can be returned to the leader node.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK every value in the columnar storage has an ID pointer (similar to CTID you mentioned), and to get the select results Redshift needs to find and combine the values with the same ID pointer for each column that's selected from the raw data. If memory allows it's stored in memory, unless it's spilling to disk. This process is called materialization (don't confuse with materialized view materialization). In your case there are 2 technically possible scenarios:

1. materialize all Age/Name pairs, then filter by Age=30, and output the result
2. filter Age column by Age=30, get IDs, get Name values with corresponding IDs, materialize pairs and output

I guess in this case #2 is what happens because materialization is more expensive than filtering. However, there is a plenty of scenarios where this is much less obvious (with complex queries and aggregations). It is the responsibility of the query optimizer to decide what's better. #1 is still better than the row oriented because it would still read just 2 columns.

Comment: _How_ does it "get Name values with corresponding IDs"? Does it scan the entire Name column, looking for them? Are they in sorted order so it can do a bisection? Is there a btree index? The question asks, "What data structure is used? What are its performance characteristics?"

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it looks like the following: every column is stored separately, broken down into chunks (blocks). Every block has metadata that stores the range of values for that column AND the range of row OIDs. So, if the query engine needs to define the OIDs according to the query filter like for Age column it is able to find and scan blocks that satisfy the condition and skip the rest, the same happens with OIDs when it tries to materialize Name results filtered by Age OIDs.